# Changing digits in numbers based on a conditions

Tags: pandas, string, series

In Norway we have something called D- and S-numbers. These are National identification number where the day or month of birth are modified.

```
D-number
[d+4]dmmyy

S-number
dd[m+5]myy
```

I have a column with dates, some of them normal (ddmmyy) and some of them are formatted as D- or S-numbers. Leading zeroes are also missing.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': [241290,  #24.12.90
                             710586,  #31.05.86
                             105299,  #10.02.99
                              56187]  #05.11.87
                  })

    dates
0  241290
1  710586
2  105299
3   56187
```

I've written this function to add leading zero and convert the dates, **but this solution doesn't feel that great**.

```
def func(s):
    s = s.astype(str)
    res = []
    for index, value in s.items():
        
        # Make sure all dates have 6 digits (add leading zero)
        if len(value) == 5:
            value = ('0' + value)
        
        # Convert S- and D-dates to regular dates
        if int(value[0]) > 3:
            
            # substract 4 from the first digit
            res.append(str(int(value[0]) - 4) + value[1:])
        
        elif int(value[2]) > 1:
            # subtract 5 from the third digit
            res.append(value[:2] + str(int(value[2]) - 5) + value[3:])
        
        else:
            res.append(value)
            
    return pd.Series(res)
```

Is there a smoother and faster way of accomplishing the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalize dates by padding with 0 then explode into 3 columns of two digits (day, month, year). Apply your rules and combine columns to a `DateTimeIndex`:

```
# Suggested by @HenryEcker
# Changed: .pad(6, fillchar='0')  to  .zfill(6)
dates = df['dates'].astype(str).str.zfill(6).str.findall('(\d{2})') \
                   .apply(pd.Series).astype(int) \
                   .rename(columns={0: 'day', 1: 'month', 2: 'year'}) \
                   .agg({'day': lambda d: d if d <= 31 else d - 40,
                         'month': lambda m: m if m <= 12 else m - 50,
                         'year': lambda y: 1900 + y})

df['dates2'] = pd.to_datetime(dates)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    dates     dates2
0  241290 1990-12-24
1  710586 1986-05-31
2  105299 1999-02-10
3   56187 1987-11-05

>>> dates
   day  month  year
0   24     12  1990
1   31      5  1986
2   10      2  1999
3    5     11  1987
```

Comment: Pure genius, man! This taught me a lot! Didn't know about the `pad`, or that you could apply `pd.Series` to explode lists. Thank you!

Comment: [`str.zfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) might be more clear than doing it manually with `pad`

Comment: @HenryEcker. A good advice as usual. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the Series as integers until the final step. The disadvantage of the method below is that the offsets do not match what the specifications say and may take more mental power to comprehend:

```py
def func2(s):
    # In mathematical operations, digits are counted from right
    # so "first digit" becomes sixth and "third digit" becomes
    # fourth in a 6-digit number
    delta = np.select(
        [s // 10**5 % 10 > 3, s // 10**3 % 10 > 1],
        [4 *  10**5         , 5 *  10**3         ],
        0
    )
    return (s - delta).astype('str').str.pad(6, fillchar='0')
```